# Setup Rails Form Builder for Related Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I do not understand how to setup forms with related resources in Rails 4.

My models:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :category
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I'm trying to setup a form where I can simply select the "category" from a drop down box.

How do I setup my controller and form view to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're using the simple_form gem, there is a notion of assocations.  There is no need to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` whether you use simple_form or not, because you aren't making changes to the `category` model, you're just using the category collection.  I'll add an answer with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, { :multiple => false } %>
<% end %>
```

This assumes you have an attribute in your Category model called `name`.

Add `category_id` to your strong parameters in your Tasks Controller.

Comment: I get this error: `undefined method 'category_id' for #<Task id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>`

Comment: run a migration and add a category_id like this: `add_column :tasks, :category_id, :integer` or rollback your original task migration add a line like this: `t.belongs_to :task`

Comment: Tried that. Same issue.

Comment: Got it to work. Was using t.belongs_to :task_id . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

An example with and without simple_form

```
<%= simple_form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.association :company %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And without sf

```
<%= form_for @object do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :company_id, Company.all, :id, :name =>
<% end %>
```

Both will produce a dropdown of company's using the name in the select list.